# Easily readable file access history on macOS Sierra Server

Tags: filesystem, server.app, file-sharing

I'm running a small company network with macOS Sierra Server and a few client Macs whose users access and modify files in various shared folders.

I want to make it easy for users to keep track on a file or folder's access and editing history.
I know I can do this via the servers log files, but I am looking for a way that makes this 'palatable' for normal users without much technical knowledge.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What sort of files as this could be a simple version control solution

Comment: It's mostly MS Office files, PDFs, etc. and nothing extraordinary. Some sort of version control might be right for this as long as it's not confusing for the average office worker. Thanks!